# change text use arraylist with onclicklistener to set next textView in arraylist by click the button

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, textview, onclicklistener

```
NewText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mainn);
ChangeText = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ph);

// Create a list of words
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("one");
words.add("two");
words.add("three");
words.add("four");
words.add("five");
words.add("six");
words.add("seven");
Words.add("eight");
words.add("nine");
words.add("ten");

ChangeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    //what code should I write here to change the text from one to two when I click the button??


      }


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop the sequence:

```
if (index < words.size()) {
    NewText.setText( (CharSequence) words.get( index + 1 ) );
    index = index+1;
    return;
}

if (index == words.size()) {
    NewText.setText( (CharSequence) words.get( 0 ) );
    index = 0;
}
```

Comment: ممكن رقم فونك او صفحة الفيس لو امكن

Comment: close when arrive to ten

Answer (score 0):

I didn't code Java since a while because I'm now coding Flutter (dart) but I will try.

```java
private int index = 0;

...

ChangeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (index < words.size()) {
            NewText.setText( (CharSequence) words.get( index + 1 ) );
            index = index+1;
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: red in index ??

Comment: Did you put `int index = 0;` as public variable?

Comment: NewText.setText(words[index+1]);      error in words

Comment: تعرف تعمل سكرين شوت للصفحه كلها؟

Comment: طلب تعديل ليها عمل الكود مده    NewText.setText( (CharSequence) words.get( index + 1 ) );

Comment: جربت على الموبايل اشتغل فعلا بغير لحد 10 بس بعد ميغير ال العاشر عاوزه يجب اول واحد تاني

Answer (score 0):

ChangeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            index = index+1;
            if (index < ayaa.size()) {
                NewText.setText( (CharSequence) ayaa.get( index  ) );
                return;
            }

            if (index == ayaa.size()) {
                NewText.setText( (CharSequence) ayaa.get( 0 ) );
                index = 0;
            }
        }

    });
```